# sa account not working anymore on SQLServer2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have been running SQLServer 2008 for some years now on my laptop.
At a certain point I cannot login anymore with my sa account (mixed authentication turned on).

I get the error message 233. This happened when I attempted to install a new application and the installation process aborted.

When I login with another account however, all works fine, except that I cannot access databases for which this other account has no access rights.

When I check the security/logins I see that the sa account is disabled and when I try do change that I get a 15151 error.

When I login with windows authentication and try to change the sa account I get a 15405 error.
So what to do? Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> SA can be disable or enabled using following script. Make sure that
>   you are logged in using windows authentication account.
>
> ```
> /* Disable SA Login */
> ALTER LOGIN [sa] DISABLE
> GO
> /* Enable SA Login */
> ALTER LOGIN [sa] ENABLE
> GO
> ```

If this doesn't work you can try logging in as a local admin and then re-enable the SA account. Restart the SQL for changes to take action.